# Find Bi(x) equation given Ai(x)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, airy-functions

It is well known that $\mathrm{Ai}(x)$ and $\mathrm{Bi}(x)$ are two linear-independent solutions of Airy's ODE: $$y''-xy=0$$

Using Fourier transform, I am able to find out the integral form of $\mathrm{Ai}(x)$, but I would like to proceed further to find out the general solution for Airy's ODE. Hence, I substitute $y=f(x)\mathrm{Ai(x)}$ into Airy's ODE and obtain:

$$
\underbrace{f(x)\mathrm{Ai}''(x)}_M+2f'(x)\mathrm{Ai}'(x)+f''(x)\mathrm{Ai}(x)-xf(x)\mathrm{Ai}(x)=0
$$

Given that $\mathrm{Ai}''(x)=x\mathrm{Ai}(x)$, I am able to eliminate term $M$ and simplify the equation into

$$
2f'(x)\mathrm{Ai}'(x)+f''(x)\mathrm{Ai}(x)=0
$$

Solving this reducible 2nd order ODE, I found that $f'(x)={C_1\over\mathrm{Ai}^2(x)}$, and this is where I am stuck: I was not able to calculate

$$\int{\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{Ai}^2(x)}$$

which is expected to be

$$
{\pi\mathrm{Bi}(x)\over\mathrm{Ai}(x)}+C
$$

according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281%2FAi%5E2%28x%29%29), so I wonder if someone could help me find this integral so that I am able to obtain a general solution for Airy's ODE.

Answer (score 1):

The Wronskian of the Airy functions is
$$\frac{1}{\pi} = Ai(x) \, \frac{d \, Bi(x)}{dx} - Bi(x) \, \frac{d \, Ai(x)}{dx}$$
and leads to
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{Ai^{2}(x)} &= \pi \, \int \frac{1}{\pi} \, \frac{dx}{Ai^{2}(x)} \\
&= \pi \, \int \left(Ai(x) \, \frac{d \, Bi(x)}{dx} - Bi(x) \, \frac{d \, Ai(x)}{dx} \right) \, \frac{dx}{Ai^{2}(x)} \\
&= \pi \, \int \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{Bi(x)}{Ai(x)} \right) \, dx \\
&= \frac{\pi \, Bi(x)}{Ai(x)} + c_{0}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for answering this question, but is there a way to find the integral representation of $Bi(x)$?